# Addin can not receive postMessage anymore after reloading the popup

Tags: cross-domain, office-js, page-refresh, postmessage, window.opener

I am making an Excel add-in by [Excel JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel). There is a button in this add-in, clicking on it launches `popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new/", "popup", "width=1000, height=1100")` and popups a browser window.

In the popup, I could use the following code to send a message to the addin:

```
if ($window.opener !== null) {
    alert($window.opener.location.href); // https://localhost/App/Home.html?et=
    $window.opener.postMessage(msg, $window.opener.location.href);      
}
```

And in the addin, I could use the following code to receive the message from the popup:

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
    console.log("RECEIVED: " + JSON.stringify(event.origin));
    if (event.origin === ...) {
        action(event.data);
    }
};
```

So it works well: when the addin receives message, it shows `RECEIVED: "https://localhost:3000"`.

However, I realised that if I refresh the popup by `cmd+r`, the popup can still send a message (`$window.opener.location.href` is still the same), but the addin can NOT receive it any more; `RECEIVED: "https://localhost:3000"` is NOT displayed anymore.

Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try working with the Office Add-in Dialog API instead of window.open? It is designed for use with add-ins. For an overview see: [Use the Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Comment: Thank you... I am going to try Dialog API for the next version. For this version, I would like to make the best with window.open...